Annoying memory leak in NODE JS in Production using RabbitMQ
We're using RabbitMQ as our message broker, when I emit a message I'n using this piece
  import { Connection, Channel, ConsumeMessage, Options, Replies, connect } from 'amqplib';
  import * as msgpack from '@msgpack/msgpack';
  async emit(eventName: string, data: any, route: string = '*'): Promise<boolean> {
    let serializedMessage: Uint8Array | null = null;
    let buffer: Buffer | null = null;
    let channel: Channel | undefined;

    try {
      const messageData = { eventName, data };
      serializedMessage = msgpack.encode(messageData);

      channel = await this.getChannel();
      if (!channel) {
        throw new Error('Channel is not available');
      }

      buffer = Buffer.from(serializedMessage);
      const result = channel.sendToQueue(route, buffer); // THIS LEAKS !!
      log.debug(`Memory usage after sending message: ${JSON.stringify(process.memoryUsage())}`);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      log.error('Failed to emit message', error);
      throw error;
    } finally {
      serializedMessage = null;
      if (buffer) {
        buffer.fill(0); // Clear buffer content
        buffer = null;
      }
      if (global.gc) {
        global.gc();
      }
    }
  }

However this code causes my POD to reach 4GB+ of RAM (and it never stops),
and noticed that it happens when sending payload of 1MB and above.
On the other hand I've tried to understand where is happens, and found it:
  async emit(eventName: string, data: any, route: string = '*'): Promise<boolean> {
    let fakeSerializedMessage: Uint8Array | null = null;

    // Fake
    const fakeMessageData = {
      eventName,
      data: {
        key1: {
          subKey1: 'key.....',
          config: {
            foo: 'barbur',
          },
        },
      },
    };
    fakeSerializedMessage = msgpack.encode(fakeMessageData);

    try {
      const channel: Channel = await this.getChannel();
      const result = channel.sendToQueue(route, Buffer.from(fakeSerializedMessage));
      log.debug(`Memory usage after sending message: ${JSON.stringify(process.memoryUsage())}`);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      log.error('Failed to emit message', error);
      throw error;
    } finally {
      // empty
    }
  }

When changing emit() to be as the 2ND form (sending a fake message), no memory leak.
We've tried multiple ways to prevent it even using the GC, but I don't like this so called solution.
Any idea how to solve this memory leak ?

Just wondering, can you print size of buffer from 1st example. Maybe Buffer.from(serializedMessage);  or msgpack.encode(messageData); is causing issue with production data. Can you cross check that ?

@DhruvPal: It's around 2MB+

if your memory is continuously growing that means somehow your memory is retained or message throughput is too high. Check this https://github.com/amqp-node/amqplib/issues/42. Try sending like 5-10 msgs on local and see that is retaining memory. Is some how your buffers are not getting cleared. You need to test using some variations.I doubt about amqplib having this kind of issue or maybe reproduce local and try upgrading amqplib version
